Currently gRPC provides keep alive mechanism at channel level ? Is there any support for keep alive mechanism at stream level?

We are having a usecase in which a client and server communicate over bidirectional stream.
The client opens a single channel with multiple long lived  bidirectional streams  with the server.
A client  transfers different kind of data over each stream  i.e (ConnectionPayload, ConfigPayload, DataPayload)

service Transfer {
    rpc TransferConnection (stream ConnectionPayload) returns (stream ConnectionPayload) {}
    rpc TransferConfig  (stream ConfigPayload) returns (stream ConfigPayload) {}
    rpc TransferData  (stream DataPayload) returns (stream DataPayload) {}
}

Currently gRPC provides keep alive mechanism at channel level ? Is there any support for keep alive mechanism at stream level?
In case keep alive is not supported at stream level , Is it making any sense to implement custom keep alive support at stream level ?

To my knowledge, establishing a gRPC channel is expensive (thats why keep-alive makes sense there), and creating a gRPC stream within that channel is not. So as long as the channel is alive, there is no reason to keep a stream up when nothing is streamed I think. Just create a new stream again...
